# How to store multiple items in local storage using an input field

Tags: arrays, variables, input, local-storage

Im working on a small database for a Vinyl collection. Ik would like to make a list of all the vinyl records i have by entering each item in an input menu wich stores the data in local storage and displays them on the same html page.

The problem is:
i can only store a maximum of 1 item in the local storage.
When i enter a second item the first item is lost.
So i can only recall the last stored item in my local store.

How can i create a list of multiple item using local storage?
i've tryed lookingit up but i just can't make it work.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#content").append("<tr><td>" + localStorage.Album + "</td>" + "<td>" + localStorage.Artist + "</td>" + "<td>" + localStorage.Year + "</td>" + "<td>" + localStorage.State + "</td></tr>");
$("#save").click(function() {




var album = $('#album').val();
 var artiest = $('#artiest').val();
  var jaar = $('#jaar').val();
   var staat = $('#staat :selected').text();
localStorage.Album = album;
localStorage.Artist = artiest;
localStorage.Year = jaar;
localStorage.State = staat;
$("#inhoud").append("<tr><td>" + localStorage.Album + "</td>" + "<td>"
localStorage.Artist + "</td>" + "<td>" + localStorage.Year + "</td>" + "<td>"
localStorage.State + "</td></tr>");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure localStorage is really a good option for that.

What you want is an array of objects (either a regular array where the items are just sequential, or an associative array where you have a key to access items). But localStorage does not support arrays, only strings, so you would need to serialise (stringify) the array before storing it into localStorage, and deserialise when you get stuff back.

Basically it would be something along the lines of:

```
var albums = localStorage.albums ? JSON.parse(localStorage.albums) : [];
albums.push({"Album":album, "Artist":artiest});
localStorage.albums = JSON.stringify(albums);
```

But that means a lot of parsing and stringifying for every change...